# get and delete working but other methods not working: restful server by phill

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, codeigniter-restserver

i'm trying to implement Phil Sturgeon's rest server and learning about authentication with api key. I'm using rest client and curl library by, again, Phil Sturgeon. program is working fine with get and delete request but while trying post and other remaining method it throws "not authorized" response.
And much more when i try to use digest authentication(here i'm using chrome advanced rest client to test)user name and password doesn't match and browser keeps showing login form always.
here is my curl tester

```
  function rest_client_example($id)
{ 
    $this->load->library('rest', array(
        'server' => 'http://localhost:81/restserver/index.php/api/example/',
        'http_user' => 'admin',
        'http_pass' => '1234',
        'http_auth' => 'digest', // or 'digest'


    ));

    $user = $this->rest->put('user', array('id' => $id, 'X-API-KEY' => 'aa72dfaa70d6aa6c2c8d26b82c08d26db979f2f0'), 'application/json');
    print_r($user);exit;
    echo $user->name;
}
```

and i'm using default example class included on that rest server bundle

Answer (score 0):

Pass API key in `header`

```
function rest_client_example($id)
    { 
        $this->load->library('rest', array(
            'server' => 'http://localhost:81/restserver/index.php/api/example/',
            'http_user' => 'admin',
            'http_pass' => '1234',
            'http_auth' => 'digest', // or 'digest',
            'api_key' => 'aa72dfaa70d6aa6c2c8d26b82c08d26db979f2f0',
            'api_name' => 'X-API-KEY',


        ));

        $user = $this->rest->put('user', array('id' => $id), 'application/json');
        print_r($user);exit;
        echo $user->name;
    }
```